# Updating the Amplify Redirect URI?

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

If we want to update the Amplify signout redirect URI in `aws-exports` how do we go about doing that?

Can we just edit the file directly and run `amplify push`?

### Update

Tried the manually editing `aws-exports` and that does not take.  I'm guessing we have to `amplify remove auth` and start from scratch...

Comment: did you find a way to update the Redirect URL?

Comment: Try `amplify update auth` and change the configuration.  After that it will probably give you a new identifier for the `domain` so if you are using OAuth with facebook or google etc you will have to go and update this callback URL.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will Try that